# why some namespace start with "::"?

Tags: c++

Why do some namespaces start with "::",
such as `::__interception::OverrideFunction()` and `::__interception::field` (`__interception` is a namespace).
Does this have any effect? I often find them in macros.

```c
#define INTERCEPT_FUNCTION_DLLIMPORT(user_dll, provider_dll, func)       \
  ::__interception::OverrideImportedFunction(                            \
      user_dll, provider_dll, #func, (::__interception::uptr)WRAP(func), \
      (::__interception::uptr *)&REAL(func))
```

Answer (score 0):

It means they are to be taken from the global namespace, even if locally there is one with the same name.